# How to set programatically height and width to framelayout in android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I want to set height and width for framelayout , if give values in java code using setlayoutparams its showing very small box, but in XML its showing properly.

This is my java code

```
 FrameLayout frameLayout2= (FrameLayout) light.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
 ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
 frameLayout2.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

*this is my xml:*
Note:Constraint layout is my parent

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LightPlaceFragment"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.882"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/l_width"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.162"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            layout="@layout/sample1" />

    </FrameLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

values given in xml so its showing properly:
[Result using XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQNj5.png)

Values in given java code so its showing very smallbox
[Result using Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQiTR.png)

How can I change the framelayout width and height programatically?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FrameLayout frameLayout2= (FrameLayout) light.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams oldParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout2.getLayoutParams();
oldParams.width=400;
oldParams.height=500;
frameLayout2.setLayoutParams(oldParams);
```

OR this

```
FrameLayout frameLayout2= (FrameLayout) light.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams oldParams= new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(300,300);
frameLayout2.setLayoutParams(oldParams);
```

Comment: Yes thanks,but i give values in programmatically its not showing properly small box only showing,the same value i give in xml means showing properly

Comment: @KalaivaniR set hight with as per your requirement

Comment: in xml i give 300 *300 its showing big square box properly but in case if i give in java code same 300 *300 its showing very small square box in right corner

Comment: i edited the question  and attached screenshots please see that and give solution please

Comment: @KalaivaniR I uploaded the answer

Answer (score 1):

Happened with me as well.

After spending so much time, I got to know that on setting height and width programmatically it takes in `PX (pixel)` not in dp which we set in `XML`.

So you need to convert dimension into PX from dp first using display factor like this.

```
val scale: Float = resources.displayMetrics.density
val resizedInPx = (widthInDp * scale + 0.5f).toInt() // dp to px
```

Where `widthInDp` is the desired dp you want to set like 300

**Usage**

```
val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = yourlayout.layoutParams
params.width = (widthInDp * scale + 0.5f).toInt() // dp to px
params.height = (heightInDp * scale + 0.5f).toInt() // dp to px 
layout!!.setLayoutParams(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 FrameLayout frameLayout2= (FrameLayout) light.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
 frameLayout2.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

(KOTLIN) If you need to update the width and height only, you can use the below method:

```
 private fun resizeView(view: View) {
    val size = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.view_size).toInt()
    view.layoutParams.width = size
    view.layoutParams.height = size

    //or (but be careful because this will change all the constraints you added in the xml file) 
    val newLayoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(size, size)
    view.layoutParams = newLayoutParams
}
```